# ¿Por que en Git Bash no me aparece para poner mi contraseña y usuario?

Tags: git, gitlab

qué tal?. Necesito ayuda urgente, estuve buscando soluciones en internet para mi problema pero no me sirvieron de mucho.
Quería saber si alguien me puede ayudar con un problema que tengo con Git.
Básicamente a la hora de clonar un repositorio, no aparece nunca para poner mi contraseña y usuario. Ya me fije en las credenciales de Windows y nada.
Esto me esta ocasionando muchos problemas, porque no me deja subir nada al repositorio en Git Lab.

Les adjunto capturas para ver si me pueden ayudar.
(Cabe aclarar que es la primera vez intento usar Git)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ahora, para subir, si no es tu proyecto, no vas a poder subir nada...

Answer (score 1):

Antes de clonar es necesario poner las credenciales correspondientes de git. Esto se hace mediante:

git config --global user.name "Nombre de usuario de la cuenta de git"

git config --global user.email "Email de usuario con que creaste la cuenta git"

Mediante cat .git/config puedes verificar si se ingresaron correctamente las credenciales deben estar las que ingresaste.

Después puedes clonar el repositorio en la carpeta que desees, es recomendable ponerlo en Escritorio. Espero te sirva mi explicación.

Comment: Eso ya lo había hecho, igualmente ese no era mi problema. Pero muchas gracias!